# Play Store App Device Catalog saying Track: Production Status: Unsupported

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to get an app working on the Google Play. It loads on a device through Android Studio wihtout any issues and it appears to be on the store correctly. The 'View on Google Play' link on my Play Console takes me to the listing but I get this message:

[image]

Trying to find out why and looking in the device catalog I see this message on all the devices I have looked at so far (about 10 so assume it will be for all):

[image]

My manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA2" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
    android:label="abc"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Build Gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.abc.def"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 9
    versionName "1.9"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Any ideas why camera2 will cause the device to be unsupported in production?

Comment: Remove these <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA2" /> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />. Camera2 is an Api provided by Android not a feature.

Comment: Will this stop access to the camera?

Comment: No with just camera permission you can access Camera2 too